# JPA or JPQL how to return single row from a many to many relationship

Tags: sql, jpa, many-to-many, jpql

Learning JPA and JPQL.  I have 3 database tables (as example): TVShow and Genre, and a Join table show_genre (having only show_id and genre_id) for the many-to-many relationship between tvShow and genre.

I have 2 annotated Java entities : 
Genre.java:

```
  @JsonManagedReference(value="showToGenre")
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="genres", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<TVShow> tvShows;
```

and TVShow.java

```
@JsonBackReference(value="showToGenre")
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="show_genre",     
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="show_id"),   
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="genre_id")  
)
private Set<Genre> genres;
```

Is there a JPA or JPQL way to find a specific row in this Many to Many, like given a genre id, and a tvShow id, can I find the specific genre object for the given tvShow id?

Comment: You don't think of "a row in the join table". You think of OBJECTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
em.createQuery("Select s from show join show.genres g where g.id = :genreId")
.setParameter("genreId", id)
.setMaxResults(1)
.setFirstResult(0)
.getResultList().get(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Can you advise me how I would do an insert into the Join table (show_genre) upon an insert into either (or both) tvShow and/ or genre?

Comment: Answer to 2nd part: JPA does take care of the joiner table insert automagically.  No worries on this part :-) . Just have to persist both side of the relationship.

Comment: @frododot actually, if you set the cascading property on this relationship it actually persists both sides. Of course that means you would have to identify one of the sides as the owner (which can create the other) and this isn't as clear in a n:n relationship as it is in a 1:n or n:1. Anyways.. i'm happy that i was able to help you in this problem.